# Does this class satisfy the Allocator requirement?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

I made a custom allocator, but my code didn't compile on msvc and I'm not sure if my implementation satisfies the [Allocator requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) (disregarding actual behavior of function implementations here). Here is a minimal example that reproduces the error on Visual Studio (16.11 P1 and 16.10):

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Allocator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    [[nodiscard]]
    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    void deallocate(T* x, std::size_t n)
    {
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const Allocator& other) const noexcept
    {
        return true;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const Allocator& other) const noexcept
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};

int main()
{
    using Alloc = Allocator<int>;
    using Vec = std::vector<int, Alloc>;

    auto vec = Vec();
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5E18WhW9T) isn't complaining for any major compiler but their msvc version is a little behind I think.

To me this looks like a compiler bug in msvc but I want to make sure before I open a ticket.

This is the compiler output:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(714,27): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'Allocator<int>' to 'Allocator<_Newfirst>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Newfirst=std::_Container_proxy
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(714,27): message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(711): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::vector<int,Alloc>::~vector(void) noexcept'
1>C:\code\dumpster\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(36): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<int,Alloc>::~vector(void) noexcept' being compiled
1>C:\code\dumpster\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(36): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<int,Alloc>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(714,25): error C2530: '_Alproxy': references must be initialized
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(715,1): error C3536: '_Alproxy': cannot be used before it is initialized
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(715,9): error C2672: '_Delete_plain_internal': no matching overloaded function found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(715,1): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void std::_Delete_plain_internal(_Alloc &,_Alloc::value_type *const ) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\xmemory(998): message : see declaration of 'std::_Delete_plain_internal'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(715,1): message : With the following template arguments:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30129\include\vector(715,1): message : '_Alloc=int'
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

### Edit

I opened a [bug ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/STL-containers-dont-compile-with-custom/1449317) for the msvc devs.

Comment: The godbolt link you have shows that the code is compiling with MSVC.  Where do these compiler errors come from?

Comment: Clean compile from clang, GCC, MSVC - live - https://godbolt.org/z/qoYnPYhYb  (have commented out unused parameters to suppress the warnings)

Comment: @NathanOliver Those errors come from my machine, which uses a newer version of MSVC than godbolt does.

Comment: What compiler version and compiler settings are you using?

Comment: VS version is mentioned in the question (16.10 and 16.11 preview 1). Compiler flags are essentially the default ones, except `/std:c++latest`. cl.exe is version `19.29.30037` on my machine and `19.29.29917` on godbolt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not.

An allocator rebound to a different value type must be constructible from the original allocator - this is the `A a(b)` row in the requirements you linked.

Your type fails that requirement.

Comment: Wow that's it. If I add the missing constructor it compiles. Nice catch, thank you